# Rest instead of direct sql for internal application data access

Tags: sql, rest

We have a layer based application architecture. It is written in C# and uses the sql objects available in .Net for data access. Some of it is a home built ORM, some is with stored procedures. We have a number of windows services that use this architecture to process data. Scaling and performance have always been issues. A new person on our team is pushing to convert our data access to use rest based data services. This would replace our current data access layer.

I don't think rest is meant for our architecture. I also have concerns about performance. I have to think it will be significantly slower. I don't see how going out of process to effectively a web service and then to the database for CRUD operations is not going to make our performance issues worse. I know rest can lead to performance improvements with caching and further scaling out abilities but that is not being addressed now. It's just a data access replacement with no bells and whistles for now. On top of this the initial implementation will not allow us to use stored procedures. All processing will be table based CRUD operations and any data massaging will be done in the C# code, no set based operations.

I could easily be wrong but I can see a disaster coming and I don't know if I'm right or if I'm a chicken little. Looking for any guidance, advice, case study references on this. Anything that can either help my case or resolve my dread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all the clients, such as Windows services etc are using stored procedures or direct SQL access, that's tight coupling. Any change in the database schema will mean all clients need to be updated to handle the change. If the schema never changes, it's not an issue. If the schema does change and the people who developed one of the services have left, it's a big issue.

If the database is abstracted away from the clients behind a REST layer, that's loose coupling. Any change in the database schema is irrelevant to the clients. The only thing that needs to change is the data access layer of the REST layer. The client facing endpoints won't change. How those endpoints interact with the database will change.

Essentially, moving from direct SQL to REST is taking a step back from your system design. To paraphrase:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE NOT PAID
```

becomes

```
https://api.com/orders/unpaid
```

and the returned object is a domain object representing a list of unpaid order objects.

So the clients move away from the implementation (select *) and move towards a domain solution. There is no more tight coupling between clients and database but a loose coupling between the clients and the domain.

Rather than speaking to a database in its own language, the clients now talk the domain language, "get all unpaid orders". They don't care how those orders are stored, or where. They just ask the REST endpoint.

This is all just implementation so far but your understanding of the business will increase as you'll be talking in Domain Driven Design (DDD) terms as the REST endpoints will accept and return domain objects rather than raw SQL.

Is this good for the business? Is it good for developers to understand the business at a domain level? If these answers are "yes", is the cost/benefit ratio of rewriting tons of client code to talk REST positive enough to make the change? Will having a REST/domain interface with the data open up new ways of looking at the data? Will that touch on profits?

The real question is along the lines of, will changing the architecture to be a loosely coupled REST integration that improves understanding of business objects and opens the door to a wider talent pool (potentially more REST coders than SQL gurus?) be worth it in terms of future proofing the business without hitting profits in the short term?

Will thinking of the business in DDD terms be worth the initial hit of moving from SQL to REST? Will that new DDD experience open up new doors in future design?

These are the real questions to ask. Caching, scaling etc are REST implementation issues, only relevant once you've answered the philosophical questions posed above.

Good luck, sounds like an exciting time for you!